# Yotz'ros — but no ahavos

Tags: ashkenazi, shacharis-morning-prayer, chagim-holidays, yotzrot

Why are there *yom tov* additions to the first *b'racha* before *sh'mone esre* in the morning and to the third, but never to the second?

(In *maariv*, by contrast, every *birchas k'rias sh'ma* has *yom tov* additions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I certainly don't know "why," but the flow of many piyyutim goes Yotzer-Ofan-Zulat.

But not all!  See, for example, the piyyutim for Shabbat Chol Hamoed Pesach, where the flow is Yotzer-Ofan-Meorah-Ahavah-Zulat-Geulah.  (These piyyutim are in the Rinnat Yisrael machzor, for example, but the ArtScroll machzor doesn't have the Meorah or Ahavah, with a note in the commentary to the effect that the composition is missing lines.)

There are also piyyutim for special shabbatot that include an Ahavah, such as Shlach, Va'etchanan, and Eikev (describing the mitzvot of shma, tfillin, and tzitzit) or the shabbatot between Pesach and Shavuot (about the relationship between G-d and Israel).  I have a siddur at home with these piyyutim, which is why I'm aware of them.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to find links online to them.

Comment: +1. Thank you! While it doesn't _completely_ answer my question — I am still curious why _yom tov_ never has an _ahava_ — your answer does weaken it quite a bit, by assuring me that _ahavos_ do, in fact, exist, contrary to what I had thought.

Comment: There are no Ahavos for any days of Yom Tov.

Answer (score 3):

In Seder Avodas Yisrael by the ריביא''ד (R' Seligman Baer) זכר צדיק לברכה, there is a big Yotzros Section. For a quite a lot of the days with Yotzros, it includes a piyut in the third Brachah (Ahavah), examples include the six Shabbosos after Pesach, the Shabbos after Shavuos, Shabbos VaYeira, Shlach-Lecha, Chukas, Nachamu and Eikeiv.

Comment: I must add that there are two versions of this Yotzros section, the Ashkenaz and the Polin (for those of you who don't know what I mean by that, Ashkenaz is south of the River Elbe and Polin is north until Lita). The version I was reffering to is the Polini. In the Ashkenazi version, there are still Ahavos but not in the same Shabbosos. I'm not sure which Shabbosos except that there is an Ahavoh that os recited on both the Shabbos before Shavuos and the Shabbos before Tisha B'Av.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77586

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but perhaps once it was seen that the first bracha is flexible enough to change once a week (it has weekday and Shabbat versions), later liturgists had license to make other additions to it. (I assume that HaKol Yoducha and Kel Adon predate the other "yotzros", is that correct? Are the former attributed to the Men of the Great Assembly?)

Comment: Re your questions: I don't know. (My guess, too, is that they're older, but it's just a guess.) What about the third _b'racha_, though? It doesn't change for _Shabas_.

Comment: FWIW the Romani Jews (Italian) have Shabbat additions to the night time yotzer=maariv aravim, which is somewhat parallel to the changes you discuss.